# Jenkins SendGrid ERROR: 550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed

Tags: jenkins, smtp, sendgrid

I set up the 'E-mail Notification' section in the Jenkins Config and I am able to send test emails using the provided SendGrid credentials. However, in post-build steps I am unable to send emails due to the following error:

```
ERROR: 550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

Based on my understanding, the Mailer plugin is not using the provided credentials to authenticate with the SMTP server. It'd of great help if someone could clarify what the issue is and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug and it has been recently fixed: https://github.com/jenkinsci/mailer-plugin/releases/tag/mailer-1.29